# VueJS disable sorting when user enters data

Tags: vue.js

I have data list which I have bind to input elements in table. When table header are clicked the data list is sorted in asc or desc. Now the problem is e.g.: when user has sort "Name" column in desc and he wants to change first row name to "Dave" from "Jet Li" as soon as he type "D" the list get sorts. What can I implement to have the sorting wait for the user to type and once he finishes he can then again click the headers and sort the data.
Issue gif : [Check issue here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzMAT.gif)

My fiddler example :  https://jsfiddle.net/bngp6oas/1/

```
 filteredData: function () {
      var sortKey = this.sortKey
      var filterKey = this.filterKey && this.filterKey.toLowerCase()
      var order = this.sortOrders[sortKey] || 1
      var data = this.data
      if (filterKey) {
        data = data.filter(function (row) {
          return Object.keys(row).some(function (key) {
            return String(row[key]).toLowerCase().indexOf(filterKey) > -1
          })
        })
      }
      if (sortKey) {
        data = data.slice().sort(function (a, b) {
          a = a[sortKey]
          b = b[sortKey]
          return (a === b ? 0 : a > b ? 1 : -1) * order
        })
      }
      return data
    }
  }
```

Comment: You have to use filteredData as a simple method, not as a computed method and calls it when the user clicks on the table heading and when the user stops typing in the input field.

Comment: I think using a `@blur` event on your input instead of a `v-model` should do the trick.
However when doing so so should also change your `computed` property into a `method` that assigns the filtered data each time you call it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [`.lazy` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#lazy).
In order to work properly, you will also need to add a unique [`key`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) to each row.

Updated grid data with keys:

```
gridData: [
    { id: 1234 , name: 'Chuck Norris', power: Infinity },
    { id: 2345, name: 'Bruce Lee', power: 9000 },
    { id: 3456, name: 'Jackie Chan', power: 7000 },
    { id: 4567, name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 }
 ]
```

See updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bngp6oas/1/)

Comment: This works until the user finishes typing when the focus is out the list get sorted. How can we stop that. Basically i want to stop sorting when user enters the data until he clicks on sorting again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `.lazy` model modifier to only update the value (and therefore the sorting) after the input looses focus.

In your code from the fiddle that would look like:

```
<input type="text" v-model.lazy="entry[key]" />
```

See the Vue documentation here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#lazy

Comment: This works until the user finishes typing when the focus is out the list get sorted. How can we stop that. Basically i want to stop sorting when user enters the data until he clicks on sorting again.

Comment: Then you can't use a computed value. Use an array and store it in "data". Then add a method to update the array only on click.